# Error when calling third-party method using WebService

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I want to send some data to a third-party application in SOAP XML format. I have added reference of their .WSDL file and the method is now available. One parameter to be sent is the CDATA part in this method.

When I test the Request and Response from SOAPUI, it works well. The data gets inserted in the third-party application. The Request looks like this:

**[SOAP UI Request]**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ xmlns:sec=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext xmlns:wsu=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility xmlns:urn="urn:ThirdParty">

   <soapenv:Header>

      <sec:Security>

         <sec:UsernameToken wsu:Id="ThirdParty">

            <sec:Username>abcd</sec:Username>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <sec:Password>abcd</sec:Password>

         </sec:UsernameToken>

      </sec:Security>

   </soapenv:Header>

   <soapenv:Body>

     <urn:ImportData>

         <Table>Persons</Table>

         <FolderId>0</FolderId>

         <Data><![CDATA[<Document>

         <Record>

    <FirstName>Test USer</FirstName>

    <LastName>Test USer</LastName>

    <IsMainRole>Yes</IsMainRole>

    <IsHomeSite>Yes</IsHomeSite>

    <AccountStatus>System Administrator</AccountStatus>

    <IsClient/>

    <UserId>test_user</UserId>

    <Email>testuser@testuser.com</Email>

    <UserName>test_user</UserName>

    <HOFirstAxis>None</HOFirstAxis>

    <ModulesIMS>2</ModulesIMS>

    <InspectionType/>

    <RoleName>Main</RoleName>

    <Extra>mmeyers</Extra>

    <FunctionalGroups/>

    <SelectAllCalendarsByDefault>Yes</SelectAllCalendarsByDefault>

    <GroupNameho>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameho>

    <GroupNameTCK>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameTCK>

    <GroupNameIMS>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameIMS>

    <GroupNameacs>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameacs>

    <GroupNameAP>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameAP>

    <GroupNameMoC>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameMoC>

    <GroupNameRCM>&lt;None&gt;</GroupNameRCM>

    <DisplayUserLang>English</DisplayUserLang>

    <UseUserRS>No</UseUserRS>

    <TimeZone/>

  </Record>

         </Document>]]></Data>

         <FormatType>3</FormatType>

         <CSVSeparator>1</CSVSeparator>

         <FormatOptions>22</FormatOptions>

         <ImportType>2</ImportType>

         <MatchType>1</MatchType>

         <ImportOptions>1234</ImportOptions>

      </urn:ImportData>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when I copy this format in an .xml file and create the CDATA part in WCF and pass to the method, it throws error.

**[Code in WCF]**

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("header", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
public string CreateXmlForImport()
{
 
    ThirdPartyClient client = new ThirdPartyClient();

        const string FILENAME = @"test.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
        XNamespace nsUrn = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("urn");
        XElement importData = doc.Descendants(nsUrn + "ImportData").FirstOrDefault();
    XElement xCdata = new XElement("Document",
                            new XElement("Record",
                             new XElement("UserName", "T12345"),
                               new XElement("FirstName", "TEST_RP"),
                               new XElement("LastName", "Test_LNAME"),
                               new XElement("Email", "test@test.com")
                           ));

        string cDataStr = xCdata.ToString();
        XCData cdata = new XCData(cDataStr);

    
   var response = client.ImportData(cDataStr);
    
    return response;
}
```

**Error:**

> InvalidOperationException: The top XML element 'Response' from
> namespace '' references distinct types System.String and
> System.Object. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or
> namespace for the element or types.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, I think it may be because they have the same element name `(namespace="", name=" name ")` but are of different types. In xml file you can try changing the name of the element or dropping it into a different namespace if the name is the same.

The likely cause of this problem is that the XMLSerializer uses XSD schema validation. You can read [the xml serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/182eeyhh(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) for more info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have given the original XML in my post. Can you please let me know what is the issue with namespace error ?

Comment: Problems may occur with the XmlElementAttribute attribute in the class of the object type.